# Display firefox extension popup programmatically

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Firefox extension and I've been looking for a way to display it automatically (with JavaScript) under certain conditions, as if the user had clicked on the icon.

I know it is possible because some extensions already do it (like Wanteeed, see image below)

[image: Auto showing extension]

I have my javascript getting all the informations that I want, I know when my condition is okay the only thing that I need now is a way to make my little extension's 'popup' magically appear

I've looked for answers as I could, I hope that I didn't miss an already existing post, sorry if I did and thank you very much for your answers !

Comment: have you tried looking to see how the extension that works like you want is written? There's no shame in programming by example, especially if the example does virtually exactly what you want

Comment: I must admit I didn't think it was possible that easily but I managed to find their JS injected for the extension, and found that they are doing exactly what Maluen says below ! 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the latest [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) format? If so, then you can't just open the popup page programmatically, this is for security reasons. From the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Popups):

> When the user clicks the button, the popup is shown. When the user clicks anywhere outside the popup, the popup is closed. The popup can be closed programmatically by calling window.close() from a script running in the popup. **However, you can't open the popup programmatically from an extension's JavaScript: it can only be opened in response to a user action.**

An alternative is to use content scripts to append a `position:fixed` div to the current page, and then to style it with CSS to match the popup style. This is probably what the extension you referenced is doing.

Comment: Yes !

I found in the MDN docs that the browser.browserAction has a browserAction.openPopup() method and wasn't understanding why it wouldn't open it, you just gave me the answer ! 

I can understand the security issues behind that !

And I finally managed to get at least part of the code of the Wanteeed extension and they do exactly what you said, thank you very much !!!